# Progressive disclosure control

Tags: c++, winapi

In the windows API, how do I implement a Progressive disclosure control?

Comment: [OT]I find creepy is that Googling to understand what a progressive disclosure control is, I got this 40-minutes-old question as the third result. :S [/OT]

Comment: It is a control you use to collapse/expand a section. >, \/

Comment: It is like the +/- buttons in a tree list view, or the /\ or \/ button that says "Advanced Options..."

Comment: The [mCtrl](http://www.mctrl.org/) Open Source library (LGPL) implements the disclosure chevron as a win32 control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gonna be a lot of hand coding, probably. If you're using it for a message box, look into TaskDialog: it has something similar built-in. Otherwise you're probably on your own.

Comment: Really, you would think Microsoft would make it as easy as an edit or button control. Well....